# CSV Data frame column show incorrect class name

Tags: r, csv

```
Date;Hours;Turnover 
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.9
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.10
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.11
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.12
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.13
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.14
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.15
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.16
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.17
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.18
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.19
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.20
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.21
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.22
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.23
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.24
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.25
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.26
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.27
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.28
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.29
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.30
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.31
01/01/2015;00 - 01;37403.32
```

I have a `CSV data frame` having three different columns one column consists of date(dd\mm\year) and second column consists of hours (24hours) and the third column consists of the demand value of electricity in each hour. I want to extract the third columns which include the numerical value only. But when I check the class of the selected column is shows me that it's a `factor` so please help me why this happen and suggest the possible solution that's the class is numeric not a factor.
I save this CSV file as  `dem<-  read.csv2("~/dem.data2.csv")` then I extract column three as  `dem1<- dem$Turnover` but when I check the class of the `dem1` it gives factor.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks, Ronak Shah for your response I edit my question with an example.

Comment: I think somewhere in your data you have a value which is not a number. You may also try with `dem<-  read.csv2("~/dem.data2.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` but this would just change the class from factor to character.

Comment: I check all of my data there was no such value that not an integer. mean all values are numeric

Comment: If that is the case then just change them to numbers ? `dem$Turnover <- as.numeric(as.character(dem$Turnover))`

Comment: Have you an old R version where `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` was default? Try `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` if you can't update for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with decimal separator make think your number is a string. Use this line

```
dem<-  read.csv("~/dem.data2.csv",sep=";",dec=".",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Yes, Its solve my problem thanks Miguel Suazo